# Android ffmpeg binary and other .so files execution error

Tags: android, android-ndk

Hi have ffmpeg/ffprobe binary and other .so files i.e. libavcodec.so, libavdevice.so, libavfilter.so, libavformat.so, libavutil.so, libswresample.so, libswscale.so.

I have put all these so files in jniLibs->arm64-v8a->...
and same for other 3 CPU architecture like x86 and x86_64.

I have put binary ffmpeg and ffprobe in assets folder with similar CPU architecture.
i don't have JNI folder, not any C++ native code in my project.

Now i am loading these so files using System.loadLibrary("") for all 7 .so files and it loads successfully.

Have moved ffmpeg binary from assets to data/data/ folder.
But when I run any command:
it shows error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/user/0/<pkg_name>/files/ffmpeg": library "libavdevice.so" not found
```

What could be the reason? any idea what mistakes I am doing?

My ffmpeg binary size is 240 KB.

Answer (score 0):

The path you are trying to use is not in the default dynamic library lookup path for either the JVM or the dynamic loader.

You can fix the first issue by loading libraries by absolute pathname or setting `java.library.path` to point there.

The second issue can AFAIK only be solved by adding RPATH entries to the libraries that are relative to `$ORIGIN`  (the library being loaded)